# Gstreamer playback using typefind

Tags: video, arm, signals, gstreamer, playback

To start with I am just a beginner in gstreamer and I am in the process of development of an application which sends video data to the listener and listener decodes it to play. For this am using gstreamer.
But before that iam trying to understand gstreamer.

I have got a standalone code which generates a pad-added signal and call back is hit.
Iam using I.MX6 board for playback.

I used gst-launch to playback a "ts file and as well as mp4 file" using the below command and it works.

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/opt/zu/test/stream2.ts typefind=true ! aiurdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! beepdec ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink demux. ! queue ! vpudec! mfw_v4lsink
```

which then i brought it into the code with perfectly using the demuxer and the required elements.

Here i find "typefind=true" is set which I am not sure how to bring it to the code. As far i understood typefind sets the src pads after finding the CAP.
This is what i got using a standalone for typefind.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Capabilities>
 <Caps1>video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188</Caps1>
</Capabilities>
```

Cap = video/mpegts

While running my gstreamer standalone to playback ts file , I get the below message

"Pipeline state changed from NULL to READY:" and it doesnt playback. It just keeps running. Below is my standalone code

```
data.source = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "source");
g_object_set (data.source, "location", argv[1], NULL);
data.typefind = gst_element_factory_make ("typefind", "typefinder");
data.demuxer = gst_element_factory_make ("aiurdemux", "demuxer");
data.audioqueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue","audioqueue");
data.videoqueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue","videoqueue");
data.audio_decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("beepdec", "audio_decoder");
data.audio_convert = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert", "audio_convert");
data.audio_sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audio_sink");
data.video_decoder = gst_element_factory_make("vpudec","video_decoder");
data.video_sink = gst_element_factory_make("mfw_v4lsink","video_sink");

   if (!gst_element_link(data.source,data.demuxer)) {
                g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
                gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
                return -1;
        }

 if (!gst_element_link_many (data.audioqueue,data.audio_decoder,data.audio_convert, data.audio_sink,NULL)) {
                g_printerr (" audio Elements could not be linked.\n");
                gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
                return -1;
        }
   if (!gst_element_link_many(data.videoqueue,data.video_decoder, data.video_sink,NULL)) {
                g_printerr("video Elements could not be linked.\n");
                gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
                return -1;
        }

 //g_object_set (data.source, "location", argv[1], NULL);
        g_signal_connect (data.demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (pad_added_handler), &data);
        /* Start playing */


// CALLBACK FUNCTION

static void pad_added_handler (GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, CustomData *data) {
        g_print("Inside the pad_added_handler method \n");
        printf("Inside the pad_added_handler method \n");
        GstPad *sink_pad_audio = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->audioqueue, "sink");
        GstPad *sink_pad_video = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->videoqueue, "sink");

        GstPadLinkReturn ret;
        GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
        GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
        const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;
        g_print ("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME (new_pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME (src));
        new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_caps (new_pad);
        new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure (new_pad_caps, 0);
        new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name (new_pad_struct);
        if (g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type,/*"audio/x-vorbis"*/ "audio/mpeg"))
        {
                ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad_audio);
                if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret))
                {
                        g_print (" Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
                }
                else
                {
                        g_print (" Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
                }
        }

        //else if (g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type, /*"video/x-theora"*/"video/x-h264"))
        else if (g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type, /*"video/x-theora"*/"video/mpegts"))
        {
                ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad_video);

                if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret))
                {
                        g_print (" Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
                }
                else
                {
                        g_print (" Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
                }
        }


        else {
                g_print (" It has type '%s' which is not raw audio. Ignoring.\n", new_pad_type);
                goto exit;
        }
exit:
        if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
                gst_caps_unref (new_pad_caps);
        gst_object_unref (sink_pad_audio);
        gst_object_unref (sink_pad_video);

}
```

I have reduced some of the code. Can you please guide what Iam missing here.?..
Iam not sure how to bring type find into the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this finally without using typefind.

If anyone comes across this post ,hope this will be useful for them.

It looks like typefind is not necessary, I used the following code.

```
GstCaps    *caps;
/* for mp4 playback use "video/quicktime", if it is ts file use "video/mpegts" , likewise corresponding to other files. You can find what to use as caps using gst-discoverer command for the file*/
caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/quicktime",NULL);  
//After creating caps link using link_filtered to the demuxer
if (!gst_element_link_filtered(data.source,data.demuxer,caps)) 
        g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
                gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
                return -1;
        }
gst_caps_unref(caps); //unref after use, then the normal code continues with generating //pad-added signal.
```

Instead of finding the caps using truefind, the above code sets the caps manually. 
Hope this helps someone.